# Javascript set unicode in textarea

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have a text area that contains the unicode: (مرحبا كيف حالك).

When I pass it to the CGI it URL encodes as:

```
%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A7%20%D9%83%D9%8A%D9%81%20%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83
```

I want to take this and set it as the value for the text area but I cannot figure out how to convert the `%D9%85...` string back to (مرحبا كيف حالك)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) to convert this back:

```
var text = decodeURIComponent( '%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A7%20%D9%83%D9%8A%D9%81%20%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83' );
// yields "مرحبا كيف حالك"
```

Comment: And if you need to encode it again you can use `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I had actually tried that but was using double quotes around encoded string instead of single quotes.

Comment: @JoelParker The type of quotes doesn't matter, actually.